# Error when computing jacobian vector product

Tags: openmdao

I have a group with coupled disciplines which is nested in a model where all other components are uncoupled. I have assigned a nonlinear Newton and linear direct solvers to the coupled group.

When I try to run the model with default "RunOnce" solver everything is OK, but as soon as I try to run optimization I get following error raised from linear_block_gs.py:

> File "...\openmdao\core\group.py", line 1790, in _apply_linear scope_out, scope_in)
>    File "...\openmdao\core\explicitcomponent.py", line 339, in _apply_linear
>    self.compute_jacvec_product(*args)
>    File "...\Thermal_Cycle.py", line 51, in compute_jacvec_product
>    d_inputs['T'] = slope * deff_dT / alp_sc
>    File "...\openmdao\vectors\vector.py", line 363, in **setitem**
>    raise KeyError(msg.format(name)) KeyError: 'Variable name "T" not found.'

Below is the N2 diagram of the model. Variable "T" which is mentioned in the error comes from implicit "temp" component and is fed back to "sc" component (file Thermal_Cycle.py in the error msg) as input.

[N2 diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6mJL.png)

The error disappears when I assign DirectSolver on top of the whole model. My impression was that "RunOnce" would work as long as groups with implicit components have appropriate solvers applied to them as suggested [here](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/theory_manual/total_derivs/setup_linear_solvers.html#theory-selecting-linear-solver) and is done in my case. Why does it not work when trying to compute total derivatives of the model, i.e. why compute_jacvec_product cannot find coupled variable "T"?

The reason I want to use "RunOnce" solver is that optimization with DirecSolver on top becomes very long as my variable vector "T" increases. I suspect it should be much faster with linear "RunOnce"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example of the [`compute_jacvec_product`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.12.0/features/core_features/working_with_components/explicit_component.html#explicitcomponent-methods) method might be helpful.

The problem is that, depending on the solver configuration or the structure of the model, OpenMDAO may only need some of the partials that you provide in this method. For example, your matrix-free component might have two inputs, but only one is connected, so OpenMDAO does not need the derivative with respect to the unconnected input, and in fact, does not allocate space for it in the d_inputs or d_outputs vectors.

So, to fix the problem, you just need to put an if statement before assigning the value, just like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the N2, I *think* that I agree with your strategy of putting the direct solver down around the coupling only. That should work fine, however it looks like you're implementing a linear operator in your component, based on:

```
File "...\Thermal_Cycle.py", line 51, in compute_jacvec_product d_inputs['T'] = slope * deff_dT / alp_sc
```

You shouldn't use direct solver with matrix-free partials. The direct solver computes an inverse, which requires the full assembly of the matrix. The only reason it works at all is that OM has some fall-back functionality to manually assemble the jacobian by passing columns of the identity matrix through the `compute_jacvec_product` method. 
This fallback mechanism is there to make things work, but its very slow (you end up calling `compute_jacvec_product` A LOT).

The error you're getting, and why it works when you put the direct solver higher up in the model, is probably due to a lack of necessary `if` conditions in your `compute_jacvec_product` implementation. 
See the [docs on explicit component for some examples](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.0.0/features/core_features/defining_components/explicitcomp.html#explicitcomponent-methods), but the key insight is to realize that not every single variable will be present when doing a jacvec product (it depends on what kind of solve is being done --- i.e. one for Newton vs one for total derivatives of the whole model). 
So those if-checks are needed to check if variables are relevant. This is done, because for expensive codes (i.e. CFD) some of these operations are quite expensive and you don't want to do them unless you need to.

Are your components so big that you can't use the `compute_partials` function? Have you tried [specifying the sparsity in your jacobian](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.0.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/sparse_partials.html)? Usually the matrix-free partial derivative methods are not needed until you start working with really big PDE solvers with 1e6 or more implicit outputs variables.

Without seeing some code, its hard to comment with more detail, but in summary: 
You shouldn't use `compute_jacvec_product` in combination with direct solver. If you really need matrix-free partials, then you need to switch to iterative linear solvers liket [PetscKrylov](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.0.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/linear/petsc_krylov.html).

If you can post the code for the the component in `Thermal_Cycle.py` that has the `compute_jacvec_product` I could give a more detailed recommendation on how to handle the partial derivatives in that case.

Comment: Thank you for point this out to me. This the code in gist:https://gist.github.com/mlauryn/f4d3f48549617110bb4f52de0141d98d
Actually the reason I used compute_jacvec_product is that it is more intuitive to me in terms of calculating derivatives of matrix wrt to matrix. Could you give some advise on how I could compute partials of matrix output with respect to input matrix variable?

Comment: I've been asked about this a few times, so I made a short video walking you through the process: https://youtu.be/7c4UJ-meHNY

Comment: Thanks for support and the video! I actually ran through the code yesterday and replaced all components in coupled group with sparse partials. The performance increase is impressive :)